# Valid query parameters - passing data in URL

Tags: javascript, url, query-string

Each time I needed query params to be allowed in the URL I've always used `http://example.com?something=value&else=value`.

However, recently I needed to convert a JSON object into a query parameter in URL to look like this `key=value&key2=value2` to be passed in the URL and my colleague asked me why would I use such technique to convert an object in the URL rather than having the same JSON object stringified and inserted in the URL directly like the following: `http://example.com?data='{"key":"value", "key2:"value2"}'`

Whilst my colleague's suggestion looks very ugly to me I could not really provide him an answer more than that most websites pass parameters using `http://example.com?something=value.` practise over his recommendation.

if I use query parameters technique `?key=value` I can benefit from Javascript's built-in features like `URLSearchParams` to use the data passed in the URL.

With my colleague's recommendation, I could simply convert the string back to an object and query what was a URL with features found in objects.

What are the drawbacks of each method and why should I use one over the other?

Comment: Likely _primarily opinion-based
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._

Comment: Nothing of value here? https://www.google.nl/search?q=url+parameters+json+stringify+instead+of+url+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: So this answer will be based on one's preferences and opinion rather than a one correct way which has benefits over the other?

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing sensitive data you can encode the data in base64 and pass on the other end decode the data , by this your data will be safe

e.g

```
let inBase64=btoa(JSON.stringify({name:'tom'}))
let url=`http://example.com?data=${inBase64}`
```

on the other end to reconvert it back

```
let jsonData=JSON.parse(atob(data))
```

For sensitive data this is not a good way to do,and the is also url [limit](https://technomanor.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/maximum-url-size/)